# Is it possible to create a Cmdlet with different functionalities

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I try to find out, if it is possible to implement for example 3 different 
functionalities within one Cmdlet.

For example: I use one Cmdlet that can change the Windows Desktop Picture, ADD a Shortcut to the Windows Desktop or remove one or more files from somewhere.

Depending on my use of this Cmdlet and my input.

The goal is to only have one command with different possibilities to use for.

I tried of course a search engine and I searched here. But also, I am not really sure what Im searching for other than my summarize title.

In Microsoft Dokumentation and in this Forum it is written, a cmdlet is for a single function. But when I can convert C# Code into a Cmdlet, then why is it not possible to choose between different functionalities within one Cmdlet?

I would be very happy to receive an answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited the question to include the specific sticking point you came across when you tried. As it is, the question is very broad.

Comment: Of course it would be possible.  However, it goes against the philosophy of PowerShell, where each cmdlet should do one task.  This is why you have several cmdlets for, say, services (e.g. `Get-Service`, `Start-Service`, `Stop-Service`, etc) and not one single 'service' cmdlet, or even one cmdlet for processes _and_ services (services are just 'special' process after all).  You should create a [module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-script-module) that exports several cmdlets, one for each task you want to mamage.

Comment: I am looking for a topic for a homework and I did some scripts with powershell in the past. I found that every Cmdlet is doing one job and I was wondering, if it is restricted in a way. But I could not find anything like that. But also I could not find anyone trying this. But when this is a philosophical question, then I missed these articles, sorry.

Comment: PowerShell doesn't enforce any restriction - you could write a cmdlet that does many different, unrelated, activities with dozens of parameters and switches to control which one is activated, but as I said, it isn't the expected way to write one.  Jeffrey Snover (PowerShell's designer) mentions this idea in his [Monad Manifesto](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/monad-manifesto-the-origin-of-windows-powershell/) that provided the philosophy that became PowerShell: "Developers no longer produce stand alone executables.  Instead, they write **narrowly focused** .Net classes (Cmdlets) "

Comment: You are looking for a "function overload" in powershell this could be done with the `ParameterSetName` of parameters in functions (see `help about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters`). It's used to create a single function that works different based on the input. Let's say a function that accepts a string and an integer and handles both different.

Comment: Ok, I will search in this direction. Thank you for your response.